# How do I use ABI with Next.js?

Tags: next.js, ethereum, abi, web3js

## Problem

I'm doing some development using Next.js and ZKSwap API, but I can't figure out how to use the ABI of the deployed smart contract.

Specifically, I want to call this DepositETH.

https://en.wiki.zks.org/interact-with-zkswap/make-transaction#deposit-eth

And it seems that I need to configure this ABI to call it, but I don't know how to configure it.

https://en.wiki.zks.org/interact-with-zkswap/make-transaction#abis

## What I Did

I implemented it as follows, but it didn't work.

```
import { Wallet, Contract, utils } from 'ethers'
import Web3 from 'web3'
import zkswapABI from '../src/zkswap.ABI.json'
const Web3EthAbi = require('web3-eth-abi');


export default function zkswap() {

    //try2
    let ABI = zkswapABI

    const wallet = new Wallet('0x1c1a49fea9a4ede1dc8e582639f498d41fa3c4a9e2ab2b9d740a4a3ec14e1cbf')
    const contract = new Contract('0x8ECa806Aecc86CE90Da803b080Ca4E3A9b8097ad', ABI, wallet)

    async function depositETH(amount) {
        const tx = await contract.depositETH(wallet.address, {
            value: utils.parse(amount)
        })
        return tx
    }

    depositETH('0.5').then(console.log)

    return (
        <div>
            <section className="h-screen w-4/5 max-w-5xl mx-auto flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
                <h1 className="mb-4 text-green-500 text-3xl">sample</h1>
                <p className="mb-2 text-center"> ZKSwap </p>
                <button className="btn-blue" onClick={depositETH}> Deposit ETH</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

## Error

In fact, when I tried to 'yarn dev', I got an error like this

```
TypeError: ethers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.utils.parse is not a function
```

Comment: your implemented github code is giving 404 error

Comment: sorry I forgot this repo is private, Instead I drop applicable code in [What I did]. Please check it,

Comment: you are already fetching the ABI in this line "import zkswapABI from '../src/zkswap.ABI.json'". Assuming you have got the correct ABI of the contract, you just need to pass it with contract address to instantiate a contract object. Thats how it works in Web3.js. In your case, the problem seems to be occurring due to the utils.parse(amount) function which you are providing in the value, not with ABI

Comment: ohh, I changed ```value: utils.parse(amount)```to  ```value:utils.parseEther(amount)```, this error resolved.

Comment: I didn't look closely at the error. I'm sorry about that. Thank you.

Comment: No Problem. Since the issue has nothing to do with ABI, you can Edit your own question and add a line about how you resolved the problem. That would make it easier for others.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use require in line 4
const Web3EthAbi = require('web3-eth-abi'); // Is wrong.

instead use
import Web3EthAbi from "'web3-eth-abi'"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).